# Avoid Multiple Next () Statement in Python Generator

Tags: python, iterator, iteration, generator, yield

I'm using a library that returns a generator.  Is there a way to start at a particular iteration without using multiple **next ()** statement?

In a simple for loop, I could do the following.

```
array = [2, 5, 1, 4, 3]

for i in array [2:]:
    # do something
```

In a generator, I couldn't do as shown above.  Instead I'll have to use multiple **next ()** statements to start at the 3rd index.  When attempting to do the same as the for loop, I get an error that said, "generator is not scriptable."

Comment: If you have control over how the generator is created, you can simply start `yield`ing from the element you want.  Otherwise by definition the preceding values must be calculated (example: generator for the Fibonacci sequence).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) does this, but in reality, it's just invoking `next` for you over and over (though at the C layer in CPython, so it's faster than doing it manually).

```
for i in itertools.islice(mygenerator, 2, None):
    # do something
```

Or to avoid per-element overhead for iterating the remainder of the generator, you can consume the elements with `islice`, then iterate the generator directly:

```
# Consumes up to two items from any iterator; note: MUST be iterator already
# for this to be helpful; if it's not, you need to start with:
# mygenerator = iter(mynoniterator)
next(itertools.islice(mygenerator, 2, 2), None)

for i in mygenerator:  # Iterate directly after consuming skipped elements
    # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) , which can slice the generator as you want -

```
>>> def a():
...     for i in range(10):
...             yield i
...
>>>
>>>
>>> x = a()
>>> import itertools
>>> for i in itertools.islice(x, 2, None):
...     print(i)
...
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

---

Please note, though you are not manually doing the multiple `next()` , it is being internally done by `islice()` . You cannot reach at the required index until you iterate till it (islice just does that for you , instead of you have to write multiple `next()` , etc).

---

The signature of `itertools.islice` is -

> itertools.islice(iterable, stop)
>   itertools.islice(iterable, start, stop[, step])

The first argument is always the iterable, then if you pass in only 2 arguments, second argument is interpreted as the `stop` index (exclusive, meaning it does not return the `stop` index element).

If there are 3 or 4 arguments to it , second argument is treated as the start index (index) , third argument as the `stop` (exclusive) , and if fourth argument is specified its treated as the `step` value.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Your solution work as well.

Comment: Glad I could be helpful.