# Python3.4: for each line in text

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.4

I have this code:

```
for x in adele_text:
    if "Hello, its me" in x:
        print (x)
```

It prints the line where "Hello, its me" is. I would like to be able to print the next line, and the line after this one. How can I print the next x each lines and maybe the x lines before that?

Would there be a way to print the last 2 sentences? Sentences are seperated with a "."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
number_of_lines_to_print = 2

with open(filename) as adele_text:
    for line in adele_text:
        if "Hello, its me" in line:
            # printing next "number_of_lines_to_print" lines
            for _ in range(number_of_lines_to_print):
                print(next(adele_text, ''))
            break  # remove if you want to continue searching the file
```

Note that the empty string in `next(adele_text, '')` is important - it helps to avoid the [`StopIteration` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) being raised in case we are at the end of the file.

Comment: Just to note ... this relies on `adele_text` being a `TextIOWrapper` (in order for the loop and the `next` to cooperate`)

Comment: @donkopotamus yeah, I don't really like the solution myself and it solves a part of a problem only. Let's see if this would be enough for the OP. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I tried to run it and it printed out this: TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator   on the line :print(next(adele_text, ''))

Comment: @bob interesting, just tested on Python 3.5, working for me. Are you sure you are using the same exact code as in the answer? Thanks.

Comment: I am not since the text from adele_text is a string, not a file! I can post my whole script if you want.

Comment: @bob in that case you should probably set the `adele_text = adele_text.splitlines()` to have it broken down to a list of lines.

Comment: I did : adele_text = soup.get_text().split("\n") then for x in adele_text do blablabla + error: TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator

Comment: @bob ah, sure, you need to make an iterator `adele_text = iter(soup.get_text().split("\n"))` to be able to use `next()`.

Comment: Wow!! It is working like a charm. It is the first time I hear about iterator. I will read about it since it seems important to understand. Thanks a lot for your time and help! =)

Comment: Hey! One last thing! What if I only want to print the second line instead of range ? How could I do that?

Comment: @bob sure, you mean just the next line after the desired? In this case, just call `print(next(adele_text, ''))` without the loop.

Comment: @bob ah, then just call `next(adele_text, '')` to skip one line and then `print(next(adele_text, ''))`.

Comment: Not quite what I expected :P isn't there away to say, print the 3rd line and lets say, the line before the one I was looking for?

Comment: @bob well, to avoid multiple next calls, the `islice()` would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32663159/avoid-multiple-next-statement-in-python-generator. To get the line before the desired, you would really need to improve the current approach, related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777188/making-a-python-iterator-go-backwards.